# Maxlength in Webview textfields for PhoneGap apps on Android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, maxlength

I am trying to implement maxlength in PhoneGap for Android but am not able to restrict characters cause it never fetches proper character code. Character code for delete key from below code is same as character code for any other key.

```
$(".limit-thirtyfive").bind("paste", function(e) {
        // access the clipboard using the api
        if (e.keyCode != 8 || e.keyCode != 46) {
            if ($(this).val().length >= 33) {
                $(this).val($(this).val().substr(0, 33));
            }
        }
    });

$('.limit-ten').keyup(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode != 8 || e.keyCode != 46) {
            if ($(this).val().length >= 10) {
                $(this).val($(this).val().substr(0, 10));
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Length Restriction on General**

You can simply use `maxlength` attribute of the input element you are referring to.

```
<input type="text" maxlength="5"/>
```

---

**Restricting Special Characters**

For getting this done, you may want to use `onchange` event of input fields. The example below restricts user to enter character `'a'`.

```
$('your_input').onchange(function(){
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/a/g, ''));
});
```

Comment: Won't work on Nexus 9 properly. I also want to restrict few few special characters.

Comment: I tried on keyup. It restricts backspace also & if user types quickly regex will not work properly. I have added on keyup code with my question